# To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files

Tags: magento2, command-line

Any Help

```
    To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-imap.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-intl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-json.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/20-zip.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/30-wddx.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
    - /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/etc/php.d/zzzzzzz-pecl.ini
  **You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need all these extensions installed for PHP on your machine. If you use PHP 7.2 on Debian you can use following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-intl php7.2-curl php7.2-xsl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xsl php7.2-openssl php7.2-zip php7.2-soap php7.2-gd
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: sudo not work brother on my putty .. can help me also how it can work

Comment: sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? it says this

Comment: try without it, which type of server do you have?

Comment: centOS 6 . cpanel installed

Comment: -jailshell: apt-get: command not found
without sudo

Comment: what does php -v return?

Comment: PHP 7.1.30 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2019 22:19:22) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: yum install php71u php71u-pdo php71u-opcache php71u-xml php71u-mcrypt php71u-gd php71u-devel php71u-mysql php71u-intl php71u-mbstring php71u-json php71u-iconv php71u-mysqlnd php71u-fpm

Comment: yum apt-get install php7.2-mcrypt php7.2-intl php7.2-curl php7.2-xsl php7.2-mbstring php7.2-xsl php7.2-openssl php7.2-zip php7.2-soap php7.2-gd
CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config Error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

Comment: I think you accidentally broke your server installation, can you reinstall the OS? Permissions of core files are wrong.